# Background image does not scale to fit the divs inside

Tags: javascript, html, css

As you can see from the picture, the background image does not scale according to the height of the divs it is covering.

The divs are blocks.

[image]

```
<div style="/* background-size:100%; */background-image: url('http://www.infor.com/furniture/design2014/images/10x-technology.jpg'); margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom: 50px; padding-top: 50px; padding-bottom: 50px;">
<div style="margin-left: 9%; margin-right: 9%;">
<div class="block">
```

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: I have a feeling that the reason is because the inner blocks are floated, causing the parent element (who has the background) to collapse. Use the [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) method, or `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: @Terry yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is about div's floated elements. Your div's height isn't scaling to bottom of floated elements not background. You have to set "overflow:hidden" to parent div.

Answer (score 0):

either if you are using background image you can add `background-size:cover` on `css`
it will wrap whole area inside of div